# No Routes Matches when passing Bearer token in swagger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I'm using swagger-editor and swagger-UI docker images and it is working fine.

Here is my YAML from swagger-editor

```html
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  description: Optional multiline or single-line description in [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/help/) or HTML.
  version: 0.1.9
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:7003/customer_app/api/v1
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:        
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT 
paths:
  /reviews:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of users.
      description: Optional extended description in CommonMark or HTML.
      security:
       - bearerAuth: [] 
      responses:
        '200':    # status code
          description: A JSON array of user names
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: 
                type: array
                items: 
                  type: string
```

But when I try to pass Bearer Token I got the error.

```
 No route matches [OPTIONS] "/customer_app/api/v1/reviews" excluded from capture: No host specified, no public_key specified, no project_id specified
```

I'm passing the token like [image: this].

Here is the full error screen May be it give some idea.
[image]

Comment: 1) Please post the code for the `/customer_app/api/v1/reviews` controller. 2) Check the Console tab in the browser dev tools - are there any errors? If yes, what's the full error message? The "No route matches [OPTIONS]" error in the backend suggests a CORS issue.

Comment: @Helen Please check I updated my question with the full error screen & when I not enter the token everything is working fine.